# Search alerts doesn't work in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, alert

We have a problem with search alerts in my SharePoint 2010 application. It's look fine when I click "Alert me" button on the search page. But when I look in the list with my alerts it doesn't show up. All other alers on the page works fine. Before we have problem with alerts on the Post list. But it was fixed after an installation of a HotFix. We using a blog site.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What type of authentication are you using?  Search Alerts are not supported with claims based authentication.

Edit-

- I don't believe the option should be available otherwise, but you
  should double check the Search app and ensure alerts are enabled, and try
  disabling / re-enabling it.
- Are there any email errors in the ULS?
- Verify you don't have timer jobs that are failing.
- I've seen this before with 2007 (in regards to inconsistent alerts), 
  in one instance it was an inconsistent farm state.  Re-running the
  configuration wizard on each server solved that issue (assuming the
  same patches are already applied to all your servers). In the
  other, Exchange did not have the machine running the timer job
  included as an approved relay.
- Your server anti-virus/malware, most packages now have some sort of
  protection against mail worms and will block port 25.  Sometimes,
  this is outright (not your case or it wouldn't work at all), and
  sometimes it will only do so after it meets a certain thresh hold. 
  The AV logs should tell you if this is happening.  Ditto for third
  party host firewalls.

If I can think of any other items I'll edit the post and place them here.

Comment: I using standard windows authentication.